# Update/Insert Associated Table data in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am very new to CakePHP 3. I want to Update/Insert relation table data.
I have `Articles` as the s Main table, and `Comments` is a related table in which `article_id` is stored as the foreign key.

Also, As I don't want the duplicate comment for the `Article`, I have set up unique key `comment_id_body` In `Comments` table.

Here is how I defined the relationship.

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Comments');
    }
}

class CommentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Articles');
    }
}
```

Here is my code.

```
$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articlesTable->get(12);

$article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';

$firstComment = $articlesTable->Comments->newEntity();
$firstComment->body = 'The CakePHP features are outstanding';

$article->comments = [$firstComment];

$articlesTable->save($article);
```

The issue with this code is it always tries to Insert a new row into the `Comments` table instead of updating the existing one. So when I execute code it gives the error like below.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

I think the error above is due to duplication of record in the table as the code above is trying to insert new record all times while we have record with same data is exist in the `Comments` table.

I want to Update `Comments` table record, and if no record found in `Comments` table then it will automatically INSERT new one while saving data by calling `$articlesTable->save($article);` method.

Comment: I think you need to use patchEntity() after newEntity(), and then save().  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities.

Answer (score 0):

You say *'`Comments` is a related table in which ArticleID is stored as the foreign key'*

But in your `CommentsTable` class you have:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Articles');   // Means a Comment can belong to MULTIPLE Articles
```

Firstly, assuming that Articles can have many Comments but an individual Comment only applies to one Article [the normal pattern], you should change your `CommentsTable` class so that the above line becomes:

```
$this->belongsTo('Articles');  // now a Comment only belongs to ONE Article
```

Secondly, the format of your foreign key does not follow CakePhp conventions so change the name of the `articleID` field to `article_id` - or consult the documentation for how to add parameters to the `belongsTo()` to use a non-conventional foreign key.

If you still get the 'Duplicate entry' error there might be a problem with your comments table in the database. (Did you make the body field unique?)

Comment: I Edited my question, and I changed my code also. Yes, I have a unique key setup as I don't want duplicate data in the comments table. My concern here is that How can I Insert/Update associated table data in CakePHP?